# Trying to use watir for IE only application

Tags: internet-explorer, watir

I am trying to use watir to automate the testing of a web application that opens only in IE (IE6 to be precise) to be precise. The site is having a number of frames.Doing my PoC,I find that I cannot right click nor view the source code.I installed the IE developer toolbar.It helps with the main page, but its not of much with respect to dialogs, popups where I am unable to do an F12 and view the source code.Some of the objects were accessible while trying to access some objects is throwing the windows frames security error.Can anyone let me know the way forward for these kind of web applications.

1.Any better page analyzer that can be used that works even when right click is disabled
2.Any way to find the proper way to access the objects inside the frames.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is fire up the resume and get the hell out. Now!  Seriously, IE6 as a browser is worldwide (outside of a very few countries where it exists primarily on systems running pirated software) a miniscule portion of browser usage.  Microsoft itself is trying to kill it and has even launched a [website dedicated to that purpose.](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) Don't even get me started on what a security atrocity it is.

Any company with a business model based on a product that will only run on a browser that [most of the world wants dead](http://www.google.com/search?q=why%20ie6%20must%20die) is a bit like someone with a business model based on selling accessories for trebuchets when 98% of the other countries in the world have moved to using cannons.

If you came today to any company I've worked for in the last 7 years and tried to sell us a product that only worked on IE6 you would be laughed out the door.

Sorry for the rant but I'm quite serious, I'd consider any company with a business model centered on a product that will only run on IE 6 to be the equivalent of a sinking ship, I'd make like a rat and leave asap.  Even if the money is good, you are forced to work in an environment where the support tools are horridly antiquated, and virtually nobody else can help you because none of us even use IE6 any more. (I shut down my last IE6 VM over three years ago and have not used it since.)  And with a prospective market that is shrinking on a daily basis, you know it can't last.

As far as frames go, they act like their own little sub web-page so you have to address them using the `.frame` method, See [this Watir-wiki page](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames) for the basics.  If you have multiple nested frame then you have to do the same thing, with your code e.g.

```
browser.frame(:name, "frame").frame(:name, "nested_frame").<etc>
```

The only better 'page analyzers' I know of are the newer versions of IE, Chrome, and Firefox, but if the app won't run on those you are Out of Luck.  You could try '[firebug light](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)' which is supposed to work on IE6+  and see if it works any better for you.

A more brute force alternative is to use [fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to intercept all the HTTP (and HTTPS) traffic, it's pretty  manual since you would be looking at each file or frame independently, with not much to assist you, but if the app is trying to hide from you, fiddler will let you see what is going on under the covers.

I feel for you.  If you have no alternative but to work on IE6 the best I can say is that you might want to consider the merits of developing strong masochistic tendencies as a means to enjoy your work.

That and whenever you find an unattended system, take it to ie6countdown.com and make that the new homepage, maybe the point will get across eventually. (or people will at least start locking their workstations)